# How to use ARN of CDK resource in another CDK resource

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I have an AWS CDK stack containing a Step Functions state machine and a lambda function. This lambda function uses the StartExecution API which requires the ARN of the state machine. I'm am unaware of how to acquire the ARN of the state machine since it is volatile and constantly changes.

I have tried creating a .env file next to the index.ts of the lambda function.

```
const stateMachine = new stepfunctions.StateMachine(this, 'my-state-machine', {
     definition: waitState,
});
```

And writing the `stateMachine.stateMachineArn` to that .env file using `fs` from the CDK stack. The result written to the .env file is `${Token[TOKEN.1056]}`. This is the same result when logging to the console. From my understanding, the ARN is not available during the current "phase" of the CDK stack, but I don't know how to get the ARN to the lambda function before the lambda function is also deployed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you pass `stateMachine.stateMachineArn` directly to the lambda function? You should be able to do it if it is part of the same stack, by exposing the ARN property from one of the Constructs and referencing it from the lambda.

If it is in a different stack you may have to export it using `new CfnOutput` and import it in your stack using `cdk.Fn.importValue`

You will have to pass it in as an environment variable to the lambda function if it is to be used inside lambda code.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure I fully understand. The index.ts for the lambda function is in the assets folder from the root of the CDK project. I reference it from lambda.Code.fromAsset. Can you help me understand how exactly I can get the arn of the state machine into the source code of the lambda function, if it is not available right away? If I use a CfnOutput, the lambda function will have already been deployed before it can use the ARN of the state machine. To clarify, the state machine and the lambda are in the same stack.

Comment: Edited the answer to indicate using environment variables.

Comment: Ok, I still do not fully understand how the state machine ARN will end up in the environment variables of the lambda function. If it is only available after deployment, the lambda function would already be deployed so it would be too late.

Comment: The CDK will make it a point to instantiate resources in the order that satisfies dependencies. If lambda is asking for a property of state machine then CDK will instantiate the state machine first. Answer from ALFmachine shows how to pass it to lambda environment. Except that I think you can pass the state machine arn directly without going through secret manager. If dependency order doesn't work for some reason then it is possible to force it using ".node.addDependcy()".

Comment: Maybe you should add some more pieces of code, more context, to give an even better picture. Like, how is it being used in the lambda (asset), how's lambda being instantiated (CDK), lambda construct, state machine construct, etc.

Comment: Ohh, I think I understand now! I'll give it a try. I guess I was misunderstanding how CDK handles dependencies.

Comment: The problem is now resolved. For future readers, pass the environment variable as props to the lambda function and make sure to use `node.addDependency()`

Comment: You don't have to use `addDependency` - the fact that you pass its ARN will let CDK know there's a dependency there automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are on the right track using an environment variable. Instead of creating a `.env` file on the fly during deployment as a means to pass the state machine ARN to the lambda function, I would use [secrets manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_secretsmanager.Secret.html) or [systems manager parameter store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ssm-readme.html), make that a dependency and inject that into the functions `environment` variables.

I am not sure without running code if the `<resource>.addDependency(<other resource>)` is needed but good to be aware of this if you run into any deployment order of operation issues...

```js
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib'
import * as lambda from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda'
import * as stepfunctions from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-stepfunctions'

export class Stack extends cdk.Stack implements cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope, id, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props)

    const stateMachine = new stepfunctions.StateMachine(this, 'state-machine', {
      definition: waitState,
    })

    const lambda = new lambda.Function(this, 'lambda', {
      environment: {
        STATE_MACHINE_ARN: stateMachine.stateMachineArn,
      },
    })

    lambda.node.addDependency(stateMachine)
  }
}
```

Comment: I wonder what's wrong with this - 
    const lambda = new lambda.Function(this, 'lambda', {
      environment: {
        STATE_MACHINE_ARN: stateMachine.stateMachineArn,
      },
    })